# Google Play Store API Search for c# or .Net Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, google-play

I am Looking for API / Service for searching App / Games Of Google PlayStore Api

Can anyone having any code or tips to complete this task

Answer (score 0):

Google API can be checked in the [Google API Explorer Page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/). To use the API, you can check out the code snippet from the article - [Alternate ways to invoke a REST API](http://vijayt.com/Post/Alternate-ways-to-invoke-a-REST-API).

Comment: Thanks but its not helpful